# Show items to publish is different with processed items

Tags: 2013-sp1

We have a Component A which is used in parent Components like B, C, D, E etc. We are removing all parent Components using custom resolver while publishing.

When clicking on **Show items to publish**, it is showing only one Component i.e Component A.

[image]

But when the publish transaction is successful, and we click on the processed items tab, it shows it published all parent Components (B, C, D, E etc.) too.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and give some details on your server infratructure, do you have an outscaled publisher for example?

Answer (score 6):

Your custom resolver needs to be installed on the server(s) where the publisher runs as well as on the server you are using for the GUI.